# ISO time as a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, iso

I want to add a new column 'timestamp' in the existing python dataframe. I tried the code below,

```
df["timestamp"]=datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).replace(second=0).isoformat()+"Z"
```

But I got the same timestamp for every rows. Actually I need a new column, which contains a series of timestamps. Which starts from a particular timestamp.

Comment: Look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

Comment: provide us a more detailed example if you want more help: what range do you want? min, max and step

Comment: Start time and time gap, for example:  start time= 2021-01-01T00:08:00Z, and time gap= 5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe?:

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime.now(), freq='1s', periods=len(df)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ')
```

Comment: Now the timestamp looks like this, `2021-12-06 21:09:04+00:00`. But I need like this, `2021-01-01T00:08:00Z`.

Comment: @Amzzz that's just the matter of presenting the datetime value , which you can do using `strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%SZ')` when you want to show it but if you must save it in that format you can use the same method, see updated answer